# Asynchronous generator behaviour

Tags: power-supply, power, current, generator, induction-motor

I have this asynchronous generator Plot (please see below)

[image]

where n = efficiency, P1 = mechanical power, P2 = power to the network, cos phi2 = power coefficient, and I2 = current.

I guess as the current increases (due to charge) the others increase as well, the only exception being the efficiency that declines due to increase of variable losses.

Mechanical power influences the network power (being directly proportional), so as mechanical power increases, so does the network power.

What do you guys think that generate that behaviour of the plot?

Comment: The purpose of the forum is to answer questions about electrical engineering design and theory. Without knowing the purpose of this set of curves or the characteristics of the load, I don't think there is enough information to do more that speculate. I would say that P2 influences influences everything else. For 100 percent efficiency and 1.0 pf, P2 would rise linearly to equal P1. Pf and efficiency  make the curve nonlinear less than P1. I2 would be similar P2 except for the influence of efficiency and pf.

Comment: After looking more carefully, it does not appear that the curves are entirely consistent with each other. The curves at and below zero input power would indicate that the network supplies energy to the generator to supply its losses when the generator output is zero. The network supplies reactive VA to the generator under all operating conditions unless there is a capacitor. Even in that case, the capacitor should be considered to be part of the network. Something like this would not be published without comment. Where this was published and what was said about it would explain more about it.